# MySQL and MariaDB instances on the same server

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, mariadb

Is there any way to install correctly `MariaDB` and update `MySQL` 5.5 to any superior version,without altering my production database?

I'm told `MariaDB` could be installed on the same server but I need to change its port.

So what are the step by step instructions to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately the people at MariaDB have provided a nice step by step installation which should work. I've done this in the past, so if you have any problems. Drop a comment with the error, I'll try to help.

Guide can be found [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/).

I would recommend testing this first before doing this on a production system, as there are small details that can be missed.

With regards to upgrading MySQL, assuming you're using a standard Linux dist using the commands:

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install`

Should appropriately upgrade MySQL binaries.

Although major version updates should be done per recommendation of the application.

Comment: It is really hard because they are not on Debian so not sure how to handle it, the commands are different and the tar file i have downloaded doesnt work on debian.